# Oracle OLAP Expression/Analytical Functions and NA Values

Tags: sql, oracle, olap, cube

This question is specific to NA values and Oracle OLAP Expression Syntax.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/olap.112/e23381.pdf

I am trying to perform some simple avg and sum calculations and there are specific cases where I will have NA values.  It does not appear to exist as part of the Expression Syntax, but is there anyway to perform one of these calcs and skip these values?

Answer (score 2):

I think possibly what you are looking for is the [NASKIP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/olap.101/b10339/x_monitor013.htm) and [NASKIP2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_options062.htm) options. These control how NA values are handled in aggregation functions (NASKIP) and in addition/subtraction (NASKIP2).

For example, here is some sample code to illustrate the idea:

```
" Set up some objects, and see how they look"
dfn test dimension text
maintain test add 'V1\nV2\nV3' " add some values"
dfn num.t variable integer <test>
" set the first one to 3, and leave the others null"
num.t(test 'V1') = 3           
report num.t

" See how the options work"
naskip=yes
naskip2=yes
report naskip, naskip2, total(num.t), total(num.t)+num.t(test 'V2') 
" Will all be 3"
naskip2=no
report naskip, naskip2, total(num.t), total(num.t)+num.t(test 'V2') 
" First 3, second NA"
naskip=no
report total(num.t), total(num.t)+num.t(test 'V2')                  
" All NA"
```

The code looks a bit odd because of Oracle OLAP's use of quotes for comments, but I've tried to minimise the effect. If this isn't what you're looking at, post some examples and I'll see whether I can come up with anything else.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a good [reference](http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-12656.html) explaining how nulls are used in the analytic functions.

Additionally, you can always add: "where  is not null" to your query to exclude nulls explicitly.

Comment: You cannot use not null in Olap Expression Syntax.  If you can I don't see it as being documented.  The link pasted applies to regular SQL.  This is different.

Comment: @davewolfs:  You're correct.  I was thinking of OLAP in the generic sense (and even when perusing your link, it still didn't click that these were somehow different).